# Android studio emulator stays blank

Tags: android-studio

I've been trying to use the emulator on Android Studio with no joy...the emulator opens, but it's too big for mt laptop screen, and stays blank, while the log just repeats "draw: no program", seemingly for ever...I did have a HEXM problem, but I'm past that now - I have installed the entire SDK in case anything's missing, and now I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you went to the SDK manager and installed ain image for your emulator to run:

Follow the following:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. Fixed it by asking it to emulate a different phone (there are a few options) so not sure what the problem was exactly, but it's OK now.